# icinga2 agent on hosts

Tags: monitoring, icinga2

I've heard that it's possible to "install" an agent on hosts and let them collect data to be sent to icinga2. If that is true, how? A detailed documentation would be helpful.

It's just that I would like to check the option of PUSH information to a monitoring system rather the PULLING from multiple hosts.